# Cannot connect to my Linux server using FileZilla and Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, filezilla

I am getting the following error from FileZilla: "Connection timed out. Could not connect to server". Similar error using putty as well.
It was working fine just a few days ago and have not made any network changes on the server since then.

I have physical access to this machine and I checked the following:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS is installed on the server
- The server have internet access
- sshd services are running on the server (checked using service ssh status)

I have tried restarting the ssh services (sudo systemctl restart ssh), restarting the server, but still I cannot connect the server from a different machine.

Comment: most likely this has nothing to do with ssh. can you ping your server? can you reach any other services on the server?

Comment: My question is how did you restart the sshd service if you can't connect remotely? Server is local? Also, the `service` command is depreciated and may become unavailable at some point in the future. Use `systemctl status <servicename>` instead to see service status.

Comment: @DavidDai, I just checked and I cannot even ping my server. I also feel now that it might have nothing to do with ssh. Any idea on what possibly could have gone wrong ?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Yes, the server is local and I can have physical access to it on request. Thanks for the information on service command.

Comment: @Ankitgupta check router, network cable etc.